# Rspec issue with method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to make a simple validation, the main issue I thing is the Rails version (I have been using RSpec with Rails 4) because I'm using it with Rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.9.3.

This is the code in my Model

```
expect(section).to have(1).errors_on(:name)
```

and it return this error

```
1) Admin::Section is invalid without name
 Failure/Error: expect(section).to have(1).errors_on(:name)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `have' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::AdminSection:0x007f81cf6e72d0>
```

My gem list is this

```
* rspec-core (3.0.1)
* rspec-expectations (3.0.1)
* rspec-mocks (3.0.1)
* rspec-rails (3.0.1)
* rspec-support (3.0.0)
```

I can make it pass with **should be_valid** but it is deprecated.

If I use **have_at_least** the error is on **errors_on**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [pull request](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1026). `have(n)`  was extracted  rspec-collection_matchers gem

You can include it or just use one of the following:

```
expect(section.error_on(:name)size).to eq(1)
expect(section.error_on(:name)).to be_present
expect(section).to have_validation_error("your error message").on(:name)
```

Comment: Same errors. 

**undefined method 'error_on' for** 
and **undefined method 'on' for**

Comment: I added the gem **"rspec-collection_matchers"**, so its working the way I'm used to, Thanks!